# Two Column Repeater Field Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: php, css, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am new to ACF and want to use a repeater field to create a two column row. It is functioning how I want (two even, halved columns). I want each column to begin at the same height as the other, therefor I set the height. But I want to ensure I am using best practices... is how I wrote this the way you would recommend going about it? I feel like there is probably a better way.

Thank you in advance.

PHP

```
<div class="bg-white">
     <div class="dib mw9 center">

      <?php

      if( have_rows('faq') ):
          while ( have_rows('faq') ) : the_row(); ?>

            <div class="parent">
              <h4><?php the_sub_field('question'); ?></h4>
              <p><?php the_sub_field('question_answer'); ?></p>
            </div>

          <?php endwhile;
          else :
          endif;
      ?>

      </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.parent {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 240px;
    width: 50%; 
    float: left;
    padding: 48px 24px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're able to add an additional class to the wrapping div (class="dib …"), lets call it '.parent-wrapper', you could simply use following code:

```
.parent-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.parent {
    flex: 50%;
    padding: 48px 24px;
}
```

No need for height, as flex takes care of it. Here you're independent from the content length. So even very long answers would be formatted correctly.

I hope that helps :)

Comment: @ZachPeach Great to hear that :) If the answer fits, please click on "accept". Thanks!